# how to display group data in separate table

Tags: php, firebase

```
I know how to get the data from database and display them in a html table, however grouping data by department seems completely not easy for me I'm a beginner to php programming. I would appreciate any answers.
```

[image: In this table i want to separate the users with the department of CITY MANAGEMENT INFORMATION SYSTEMS AND INNOVATION DEPARTMENT in another table but my code is only for fetching the data from the database. pls help me to achieve this]

```
I know how to get the data from database and display them in a html table, however grouping data by department seems completely not easy for me I'm a beginner to php programming. I would appreciate any answers.

<tbody>   
@php $i=1; @endphp
//@forelse ($accountingUser as $key => $item)

<tr>
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['fullname'] }}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['password'] }}</td>    
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['department'] }}</td>  
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['email'] }}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['datecreated'] }}</td>
<td class="text-center">{{ $item ['dateapproved'] }}</td>                                                               <td class="text-center"><span class="badge badge-success">{{ $item ['status'] }}</span></td>
            
</tr>
@empty
<tr>
   <td>No Record Found</td>
</tr>
 @endforelse
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you using laravel ? (just to double-confirm)

Comment: yes im using laravel

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you want to render the table, but you can try something like this:

```
$data = [];

foreach ($accountingUser as $user) {
    $department = $user['department'];

    if (!array_key_exists($department, $data)) {
        $data[$department] = [];
    }

    $data[$department][] = [
        'fullname' => $user['fullname'],
        'password' => $user['password'],
        // fill other user data...
    ];
}

// render the table
echo '<table>';
foreach ($data as $department => $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['fullname'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['password'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: thank you for your reply appreciate it very much

Comment: @itspigwithtail, If the answer is correct, can you, please, accept the answer ;)